# Angularjs: ng-model not displaying properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have a parent and child controller relationship. This is a non-working mockup of the basic functionality. I'm sure anyone more competent than me can get it working for a Plunker or Fiddle model. (So there is probably something wrong with: **$scope.data.contactList = [{ID: 1, Email: "someemail@email.com"}, {ID: 2, Email: "anotheremail@email.com"}];**)  I tried creating some objects for the contactList array.

Anyway. I want to be able to click a link in the second table in the code below to invoke EditShowContact. In my actual app, this will show a hidden div and it will obviously display more properties of a contact than just the email.

In my actual program, the values of the table are filled out properly (i.e. my ng-repeat directive is working fine), but I cant seem to get the ng-model directive to respond. I've tried various different ways and nothing seems to work.

```
<html ng-app="myApp"><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ContactsController', function ($scope)
{   
    this.currentContactID = null;
    this.EditShowContact = function(intContactID)
    {   
        this.currentContactID = intContactID;
        //this.currentContact = $scope.data.contactList[intContactID]; unclear why this assignment fails
    };
});

app.controller('ActionsController', function ($scope)
{   $scope.data = {}; 
    $scope.data.contactList = [{ID: 1, Email: "someemail@email.com"}, {ID: 2, Email: "anotheremail@email.com"}];    
});

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ActionsController as ActCtrl">

<div ng-controller="ContactsController as ContactsCtrl">
    <table border = "1";>
        <tr><th>Email</a></th>
            <th>Name</th></tr>
    </table>
    <div >
        <table  ng-repeat="Contact in ContactsCtrl.data.contactList" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="ContactsCtrl.EditShowContact(Contact.ID)" style="padding-left: 5px;">{{Contact.Email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{Contact.Name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="input" ng-model="ContactsCtrl.data.contactList[currentContactID].Email"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few errors here such as :

`ContactsCtrl` has no information about the `ContactList`. You are trying to find object in array using ID in place in `index` using `<table>` element inside `<div>` and more..

Bascially, i have reduced the need of two controllers to one and made a [Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QgAqMbFzJPSib8rMGgYJ?p=preview).

Comment: Nevermind. I just figured out my huge oversight with your help. In my full program, I was using the Contact.ID to reference a nonexistent index of contactList. It just happened to be the case in the demo code that the ID matched with the indices. That explains why my assignment was failing.